# Creating a jQuery plugin that uses object

Tags: jquery, function, object, plugins

I am trying to make for jQuery that uses functions on an object.

What I've been trying: (index.html in script tags after adding jQuery and plugin.js)

```
var object = new myObject("#selected-div");
object.jQueryMadeFunction();
```

And the plugin.js:

```
function myObject(param) {
    this.param = $(param);
}

$.fn.jQueryMadeFunction = function () {
    this.param.css({
        background: "red",
        height: "100px",
        width: "100px"
    });
}
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong, I have tried multiple things to get this working but now I am completely stuck. What's going wrong and how exactly do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
function myObject(param) {
    this.param = $(param);
}

$.fn.jQueryMadeFunction = function () {
    this.css({
        background: "red",
        height: "100px",
        width: "100px"
    });
}

var object = new myObject("#selected-div");
object.param.jQueryMadeFunction();
```

and here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgapon79/

you could return the object like so:

```
function myObject(param) {
    return $(param);
}

object.jQueryMadeFunction();
```

is it that what you mean?

Comment: Problem doing it this way is that I have to call the function on the objects parameter and not the object itself, the object itself merely selects a div for now, I want future functions to find the parameter itself it needs depending on what function you're calling. No way of doing this?

Comment: The return did exactly what I needed, I can't believe I didn't try this out of everything. Thanks!